# Why does IOTA use Winternitz signatures?

Tags: winternitz

I found this on the [Wikipedia IOTA article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOTA_(technology)#Cryptography):

> IOTA uses Winternitz hash-based cryptography signatures instead of elliptic curve cryptography (ECC).[30][31] Hash-based signatures are much faster than ECC.[32]

Is speed the complete reason, or are their other factors that went into the decision?

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons is quantum-security.

Traditional cryptocurrencies base their security on elliptic-curve cryptography. Classical examples of such algorithms are the RSA Cryptosystem, Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange or Digital Signature Algorithm, all of which are known to be vulnerable to quantum computers. Winternitz hash-based signatures, on the other hand, are largely resilient to quantum computers.

Comment: Immune is a strong word; "resilient" is more accurate.

Comment: @Helmar I took your comment to heart. :)