# What is the "main" reason for using Winternitz signatures?

Tags: winternitz

What is the primary reason the developers chose Winternitz signatures?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is to be quantum-secure:

- https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/1113/249

And secondly because there aren't many alternative quantum-secure signature schemes to begin with:

- https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/1253/249